# Error en sintaxis MySQL/JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, poo, interfaz-gráfica, sintaxis

Buenas, tengo el siguiente código y no se porqué me está fallando. Creo que es un error en mi sintaxis porque al escribir el siguiente código fue donde el programa dejó de reconocer todas mis variables.

```
     import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author luis
 */
public class compra extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ConexionBD con = new ConexionBD();
    Connection cn = con.conexion();

    /**
     * Creates new form compra
     */
    public compra() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tabla2();
        tabla();

    }
    void tabla(){
DefaultTableModel modelo =new DefaultTableModel();
modelo.addColumn("Id");
modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
modelo.addColumn("Cantidad");
modelo.addColumn("Precio");
modelo.addColumn("Descripcion");
modelo.addColumn("Proveedor");
modelo.addColumn("Stock");
productos.setModel(modelo);

String sql = "SELECT * FROM inventario";
String datos[] = new String [7];
Statement st;

        try {
            st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet se = st.executeQuery(sql);

            while(se.next()){
            datos[0]=se.getString(1);
            datos[1]=se.getString(2);
            datos[2]=se.getString(3);
            datos[3]=se.getString(4);
            datos[4]=se.getString(5);
            datos[5]=se.getString(6);
            datos[6]=se.getString(7);
            modelo.addRow(datos);
            }//fin del while
                productos.setModel(modelo);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}//Fin del Metodo Tabla


     void tabla2(){
DefaultTableModel modelo2 =new DefaultTableModel();
modelo2.addColumn("Id");
modelo2.addColumn("Id Cliente");
modelo2.addColumn("Nombre");
modelo2.addColumn("Precio");
modelo2.addColumn("Cantidad");
compra.setModel(modelo2);

String sql = "SELECT * FROM ventas";
String datos2[] = new String [5];
Statement st;

        try {
            st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet se = st.executeQuery(sql);

            while(se.next()){
            datos2[0]=se.getString(1);
            datos2[1]=se.getString(2);
            datos2[2]=se.getString(3);
            datos2[3]=se.getString(4);
            datos2[4]=se.getString(5);
            modelo2.addRow(datos2);
            }//fin del while
                productos.setModel(modelo2);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}//Fin del Metodo Tabla2

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        productos = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        compra = new javax.swing.JTable();
        seleccionar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cantidadtxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        idclientetxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        productotxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        preciotxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        comprar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        productos.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(productos);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 740, 190));

        compra.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(compra);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 520, 740, 130));

        seleccionar.setText("Seleccionar");
        seleccionar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                seleccionarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(seleccionar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 200, -1, -1));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("Id Producto");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 250, 120, 40));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("Producto");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 290, 120, 40));

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel5.setText("Precio");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 330, 120, 40));

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel6.setText("Cantidad");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 370, 120, 40));

        cantidadtxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        cantidadtxt.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        cantidadtxt.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        cantidadtxt.setText("Escriba la cantidad del producto deseada");
        cantidadtxt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cantidadtxtActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(cantidadtxt, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(260, 370, 300, 40));

        idclientetxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        idclientetxt.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        idclientetxt.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        idclientetxt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                idclientetxtActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(idclientetxt, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(260, 250, 300, 40));

        productotxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        productotxt.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        productotxt.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        productotxt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                productotxtActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(productotxt, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(260, 290, 300, 40));

        preciotxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        preciotxt.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        preciotxt.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        preciotxt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                preciotxtActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(preciotxt, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(260, 330, 300, 40));

        comprar.setText("Agregar al carrito");
        comprar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                comprarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(comprar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 200, -1, -1));

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/2017-16-11-16-16-41.jpeg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(-560, 10, 1310, 640));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void idclientetxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                            

    private void seleccionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
               int fila = productos.getSelectedRow();
        if(fila>=0){
            idclientetxt.setText(productos.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
            productotxt.setText(productos.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
            preciotxt.setText(productos.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString());


        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione una fila");
        }//fin del else
    }                                           

    private void comprarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
                                    try {
                                        PreparedStatement pps;
                                            pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ventas (nombre,precio,cant)VALUES (?,?,?)");
            pps.setString(1, prodxuctotxt.getText());
            pps.setInteger(2, preciotxt.getText());
            pps.setInteger(3, cantidadtxt.getText());
            pps.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro exitoso!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        tabla2();
        this.productotxt.setText("");
        this.preciotxt.setText("");
        this.cantidadtxt.setText("");
    }                                       




    }                                       

    private void productotxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void preciotxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void cantidadtxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(compra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(compra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(compra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(compra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new compra().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField cantidadtxt;
    private javax.swing.JTable compra;
    private javax.swing.JButton comprar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField idclientetxt;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField preciotxt;
    private javax.swing.JTable productos;
    private javax.swing.JTextField productotxt;
    private javax.swing.JButton seleccionar;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Sospecho que es un error en mi sintáxis de MySQL pero no logro ver cual es. Cualquier ayuda se aprecia.

EDIT 2: Borre el codigo de mi programa porque necesitaba compilar algo, pero el error persistió y como quiera ninguna variable me quiere agarrar.

Incluyo el codigo así como un screen de como se ve en Netbeans a ver si se da una idea mas clara de mi problema.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo tienen `precio` y `cant` en tu base de datos?

Comment: Son campos tipo INT

Comment: Debes darnos alguna manera de reporducir el problema... por lo que dices, es un problema de tu compilador y no de codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa que cada método tenga su llave abierta y cerrada correctamente, generalmente si olvidas cerrarla, se marcará todo el código debajo de él en error.

Luego de copiar tu código en mi compilador, tuve el mismo error.

Revisando un poco las llaves, en la **línea 273** hay una llave de más y al removerla, el código mejoró.

Justo encima de este método:

```
}  // < esta es la llave                                     

private void productotxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```